# Shell command "echo hello word" from access vba always return "File not found"

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access-2013

Windows 8.1 pro Access 2013 32bits

I can't manage to have shell to work.
The vba code below returns "File not found".
Thank you for your help.

```
Dim PID As Variant
Dim strcmd As String

strcmd = "echo Hello World"
PID = Shell(strcmd, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Try this: `strcmd = "cmd.exe /K echo Hello World"`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.